# Getting weird error in Laravel Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, laravel-5.6

i am using laravel 5.6 with this youtube api

> https://github.com/alaouy/Youtube

i am trying to search result with paginate like this

```
$params = [
        'q'             => $request,
        'type'          => 'video',
        'part'          => 'id, snippet',
        'maxResults'    => 20
    ];

    // $search = Youtube::searchAdvanced($params, true);

    $search = Youtube::paginateResults($params, null);

    $info = $search['info'];

    $nextpagetoken = $info['nextPageToken'];



    return view('search.index', compact('search'));
```

and my view

```
@foreach($search as $result)
  @foreach($result as $video)
  {{ dd($video->snippet->title) }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

my result
[image]

but problem is when i use `{{ $video->snippet->title }}` getting error
[image]

Comment: why are you showing a picture of the error message?

Comment: @tehhowch for showing actuall error which is i don't understand

Comment: That means snippet is null or property title not exists.

Comment: but when i use `dd();` its showing me result

Comment: you have to check what $search contains, can you post image here with dd

Comment: `http://prntscr.com/kkqqbg` here is the search dd result

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access title as an object, but it is an array.

I would try with something like:
$video->snippet['title']

(Sorry for not using Markdown syntax, I'm using my smartphone for this answer)

---

I guess that dd() is smart enough to know the difference between the two and display both of them properly.

Comment: i fixed it but not like that thanks for answering me

Comment: You're welcome, we would like to at least know the theory behind the solution :)

Comment: i added my answer

Answer (score 0):

When i `dd($search);`check i am getting 2 array

```
array:2 [▼
 "results" => array:20 [▶]
 "info" => array:6 [▶]
]
```

so i use

```
$results = $search['results'];// for videos only

$info = $search['info']; // For Other info's
```

now i can use foreach in view

```
@foreach($results as $video)
  <div class="row boxhead">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a href="{{ url('watch/' . $video->id->videoId)}}">
      <img src="{{$video->snippet->thumbnails->medium->url}}" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <a href="#">
      <h1 style="font-size: 17px;">{{ $video->snippet->title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ $video->snippet->channelTitle }}</p>
      <p>{{ $video->snippet->description }}</p>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <hr>
@endforeach
```

its works fine